# ComboBox, added items not showing up in list when executing code

Tags: vba, excel

I got a small problem, I'm adding items to my combobox in my userform but they don't show up in the combobox when I execute the code...

I'm trying the following code

```
Private Sub period_input_Change()

With period_input

.AddItem "Apple"
.AddItem "Sugar"

End With
End Sub
```

Also tried this one

```
Private Sub box_action()

With Sheets(1).period_input
    .AddItem "hello"
    .AddItem "mongoasd"
End With

End Sub
```

It simply shows up as an empty column ( no string is there ). Anyone knows the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to add the items during the initialization phase of the form:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    With Me.period_input
        .AddItem "hello"
        .AddItem "mongoasd"
    End With
End Sub
```

Otherwise, I see no problem with the code.